# Windows phone - Tile with picture in the middle and text at the bottom

Tags: xaml, windows-phone

I'm working on a windows phone app , and wanted to make something similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcTvs.jpg).

I tried to use a square button then add a picture :

```
<Button Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10">
                    <Button.Background>
                        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Assets/Marker.png"/>
                    </Button.Background>

</Button>
```

But I didn't find a way to add text at the bottom of the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Button Grid.Row="1" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
        VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
        Margin="10">
                    <Button.Background>
                        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Assets/Marker.png"/>
                    </Button.Background>
       Button Text
</Button>
```

Comment: @Wolfgang no sweat, have a great weekend!

Comment: Oh I might add though, when you start getting into wanting to do some real custom/cool stuff, you'll want to start digging into the style templates of controls to get what you really want....but I figured that answer would suffice for now.

Comment: Sure, so let's think about that for a sec. You're currently loading your image as an ImageBrush to the `Background` dependency property right? So it would make sense that when you set a Brush color as your Background, it's going to overwrite the other declared Background because there's only one property for it. You have multiple options though, you could plop your image directly in the button, or me personally, I'd customize a Button template with another object to host the image and pass in the file path probably using the `Tag` property. Then you could set your color, your image, everything